# Java RegEx with lookahead failing

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

In Java, I was unable to get a regex to behave the way I wanted, and wrote this little JUnit test to demonstrate the problem:

```
public void testLookahead() throws Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ABC(?!!)");
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABC").find());
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABCx").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!x").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("blah/ABC!/blah").find());

    p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}(?!!)");
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABC").find());
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABCx").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!x").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("blah/ABC!/blah").find());

    p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}(?!!)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABC").find());
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABCx").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!x").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("blah/ABC!/blah").find()); //fails, why?

    p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{3}(?!!)");
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABC").find());
    assertTrue(p.matcher("ABCx").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("ABC!x").find());
    assertFalse(p.matcher("blah/ABC!/blah").find());  //fails, why?
}
```

Every line passes except for the two marked with the comment.  The groupings are identical except for pattern string.  Why would adding case-insensitivity break the matcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests fail, because in both cases, the pattern `[A-Z]{3}(?!!)` (with `CASE_INSENSITIVE`) and `[A-Za-z]{3}(?!!)` find at least one match in `"blah/ABC!/blah"` (they find `bla` twice).

A simple tests shows this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}(?!!)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("blah/ABC!/blah");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints:

```
bla
bla
```

Comment: DUH!  All answers are correct, and I'm feeling sheepish for not seeing it myself.  This answer gets the win for also telling me how I should have found it on my own...

Answer (score 1):

Those two don't throw false values because there are substrings within the full string that match the pattern. Specifically, the string `blah` matches the regular expression (three letters not followed by an exclamation mark). The case-sensitive ones correctly fail because `blah` isn't upper-case.